# Error 403 connecting to localhost/<?=$_SERVER[%27PHP_SELF%27]?>

Tags: php, authentication, registration

I get a 403 error wheni get redirected to localhost/ from my login or registration scripts.

here are my scripts:

login:

```
    <html>
<center>
<head>
 <title>Login</title>
<font face="Courier" color="green">
<body background=background.png no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover
   >

<h1>Login</h1>
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
 Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
 Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" />
 </form>
 <?php
 } else{
 require_once("db_const.php");
 $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
 #check connection
 if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
 echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mqsqli->connect_errno} : {$mysql->connect_error}</p>";
 exit();
}

$userame = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username LIKE '{$username}' AND password LIKE '[$password]' LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if (!$result->num_rows == 1) {
echo "<p>Invalid username/password combination</p>";
} else {
echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";

//do stuff
}
}
?>
 </font>
</body>
</center>
</html>
```

Registration :

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Register </title>
</head>

<center>
<font face="courier"  color="green">
 <body background=background.png no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   >
<h1> Register</h1>

<?php
require_once("db_const.php");
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  ?>    



    <form action="  <?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
    Age: <select name="Age">
         <option value="12-13"> 12-13 </option>
         <option value="14-15"> 14-15 </option>
         <option value="16-17"> 16-17 </option>
         <option value="18+"> 18+ </option> 
         </select>
         <br />
   Gender: <select name="Gender">
         <option value="male"> male </option>
         <option value="female"> female </option> 
         </select>
         <br />


  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="register" />
 </form>
 </font>
</center>
<?php
} else {
 $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_AGE, DB_Gender);
 if ($mysqli->connect_errno)     {
echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
exit();
}


# prepare data for insertion
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password =$_POST['password'];
$age =$_POST['Age'];
$gender =$_POST['Gender'];

$exists = 0;
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username from users WHERE username = '{$username}' LIMIT 1");
if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
$exists = 1;
}

if ($exists == 1)  echo "<p> Username already exists!</p>";
else {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('id', 'username', 'password', 'age', 'gender')
              VALUES (NULL, '{$username}', '{$password}', '{$age}'. '{$gender}')";

    if ($mysqli->query($sql)) {
    //echo "New Record has id" .$mysql->insert_id;
    echo "<p>Registered successfully!</p>";
    } else{
    echo "MySQL error no {mysql->errno} : {$mysql->error}</p>";
    exit();
    }
}
  } 
  ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please forgive my noobishness, Thanks in advance!

Also, some people may comment that i should hash or salt my passwords, but that wont be necessary for this project.

Comment: A `403` means 'access denied', this probably doesn't have anything to do with your script. Check your webserver/webhost settings/

Answer (score 0):

you must use  **echo** in this line  :

```
   action="<?php  echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"
```

Comment: just tried that on the Register file. heres what i got :

 `Warning: mysqli::mysqli() expects parameter 5 to be long,           string given in C:\wamp\www\btyse\register.php on line 46`
 
`Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: Couldn't fetch     mysqli in C:\wamp\www\btyse\register.php on line 60`

`Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\wamp\www\btyse\register.php on line 70`

Comment: This is another Error bro , it's not about you question , you must search for your new question , or just think about it !